# How do you handle "Sync Framework does not automatically handle the deletion of rows that no longer satisfy a filter condition"

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd918848.aspx

"It is important to understand that a scope is the combination of tables and filters. For example, you could define a filtered scope named sales-WA that contains only the sales data for the state of Washington from the customer_sales table. If you define another filter on the same table, such as sales-OR, this is a different scope. If you define filters, be aware that Sync Framework does not automatically handle the deletion of rows that no longer satisfy a filter condition. For example, if a user or application updates a value in a column that is used for filtering, a row moves from one scope to another. The row is sent to the new scope that the row now belongs to, but the row is not deleted from the old scope. Your application must handle this situation."

I am just wondering someone can shed some light on how to handle "Sync Framework does not automatically handle the deletion of rows that no longer satisfy a filter condition"?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sync providers will (as part of the provisioning step) automatically create tombstone tables and triggers to track row deletions. When rows are not deleted, but updated in such a way, as to fall out of the scope, then the automatically generated schema won't log these as deletions. It will log them as updates. So to extend the Microsoft example, assume your  application is syncing only Washington data to Washington sales reps. Some sales that were originally entered as Washington sales are corrected and moved to Oregon. The sync framework won't know that it should remove these now-Oregon records from the Washington reps' local databases.

You have a couple of options to solve this:

- Modify the provisioning tools to generate triggers that would handle the situation, instead of the default triggers that don't. Look into extending SqlSyncScopeProvisioning to accomplish this. If done correctly, this is probably the most scale-able/extensible solution.
- Modify your application to detect the attempt to move a row out of a scope and have the application delete the row and re-insert it instead of just updating it (probably in a stored procedure). If you already use stored procedures to handle updates, this might be a good option.
- Add a background service or process that goes through and looks for records that don't match the scope and delete them. This may end up being the easiest solution - especially if your application is already deployed.